Postfix header_checks regular expression not working
I have the following rules that are not working:
if !/^From:\s(.+@domain\.com)/
/^Subject: (.*?)$/ REPLACE Subject: [EXT] $1
endif

It suppose to alter Subject line by adding [EXT] as prefix if if not comming from email@domain.com
Any ideea why?

"Many people overlook the main limitations of header and body_checks rules: These  rules operate on one logical message header or one body line at a time."
